# Javascript not showing up in Rails 4. (Highchart)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts, turbolinks

I've included Highcharts in a simpler Rails Application and it works just fine.  but when I did the same thing in a more complex Rails Application the Javascript code the Chart is not showing up.

here's what I did so far:

Gemfile

```
 gem "highcharts-rails", "~> 3.0.0"
```

application.js

```
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Chart</div>
  <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;">
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});
</script>
</div>
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong? Google tells it might have something to do with turbolinks, but then it wouldnt work on the other application too...

And quick second question.  How could I add this code to channel.js.coffee so there's no js on this page?
thanks in advance!

Comment: can you verify highcharts is being loaded? are you seeing any errors in the console? as for your second question, add ` //= require highcharts` to the top of channel.js.coffee and remove from application.js

Comment: Thanks! There was an error at some other javascript fragment and therefore no javascript was loadet at all. Whenever I uncomment that part it works.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the latest Highcharts source, it fixes this problem: [code.highcharts.com](http://code.highcharts.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something very similar to this when I started working with highcharts. I know this question is a bit old, but I wanted to write this for reference in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Here is what I did to get my charts to work (for reference, I'm running Rails 4.0.2 and ruby 2.1.1. and the latest highcharts with the latest highcharts-rails gem):

First, be sure that all the highcharts.js files are loaded into your assets/javascript directory.

In your application.js file, you should have the following in this order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs   
//= require turbolinks
//= require highcharts
//= require_tree .
```

Second, to get the code out of your show.html.erb file, I don't know about coffeescript, but you can create a js file in /assets/javascript called chart.js. Put your javascript into this file, starting with

```
$(function () {
```

Make sure that ('#container') in your chart.js matches the id of the div in your html.erb file. Like this:

/assets/javascript/chart.js

```
$('#container').highcharts({
```

show.html.erb:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

I didn't need to remove or turn off turbolinks to get any of this to work. However, when I set up my navbar links, I wanted my pages to refresh upon reopen (to ensure the latest information was presented, not the cached information) so in my navbar, I did remove the turbolinks functionality by adding data-no-turbolinks to the navbar div which contained my links. As follows:

```
<div class="nav" data-no-turbolink>
   ... navbar code here 
</div>
```

Here's a link to the github repo for turbolinks - read the documentation as it gives good information  on what turbolinks does, why it's helpful, and (when you don't want to use it) how to turn it off.
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/blob/master/README.md

One last thing - when I finally got my charts to render (tada!), they had the highcharts themes applied. I simply removed the highchart theme folder from /assets/javascript and they look great.